# Opencart PHP HELP (order admin alert)

Tags: php, opencart

So im using opencart and I found this code to get the payment and shipping address to come with the order alert.

```
$text .= $language->get('text_new_payment_address') . "\n";
$text .= str_replace('
', "\n", $template->data['payment_address']) . "\n\n";
$text .= $language->get('text_new_shipping_address') . "\n";
$text .= str_replace('
', "\n", $template->data['shipping_address']) . "\n\n";
```

So i'm using this code to bring in an orders payment address and shipping address through the admin order alert e-mail but when it comes through it has `<br>` tags in it.

```
Jon Fish<br />Heritage Road<br />London<br />N41<br />United Kingdom
```

I would like to get rid of the `<br>` tags and display like so:

Jon Fish
Heritage Road
London
N41
United Kingdom

Any help would be muchly appreciated.

Comment: You should look into the `nl2br()` function if you're getting `<br />` tags in your email. http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: You should also have a look at the Opencart script itself; that's where you'll have to implement the `nl2br()` function into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you say about model/checkout/order.php
 `addOrder()`
it used -

> $mail->setText(html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

you must use `$mail->setHtml($text);`

if this does not help try use "\r\n"

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) like so:

```
$string = "Jon Fish<br />Heritage Road<br />London<br />N41<br />United Kingdom";
$string = str_replace(array('<br/>', '<br />'), ' ', $string);
echo $string;
```

**Output:**

```
Jon Fish Heritage Road London N41 London United Kingdom
```

**Codepad: http://codepad.org/ePdJtXFU**

Comment: I have now updated what it should look like, Thanks Amal but I wanna make sure you understood properly because I didn't format the question properly.